# Need help removing part of filename from url with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to reformat my url to be a bit shorter. Right now the links end up as this: website.com/image?id=name.jpg

What I want to have the link come out as is m.website.com/name, without the file exension or image.php file in the url. I figure mod_rewrite is the way to do it, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it so someone accessing the URL http://m.website.com/name gets served the content for http://website.com/image?id=name.jpg, you first need to check the hostname for *m.website.com*, then match the *name* part of the URI. Using that match, you can *proxy* the request (using a **[P]**) or, if both `website.com` and `m.website.com` are hosted on the same server, just simply internally rewrite. Try putting this in your .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
# check the host (NC = no case)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.website\.com$ [NC]
# don't rewrite /image
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image
# Match the first non-slash word and rewrite
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /image?id=$1 [L]
```

This will rewrite http://m.website.com/name to /image?id=name.jpg, but it will not rewrite http://m.website.com/path/name. If you want paths (and everything else) to be included in the *id* parameter, change the **([^/]+)** to **(.*)** in the RewriteRule.

Comment: `R` is used for external redirects! remove it!